# Can you have a web server and normal using same router?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, router

I am wondering if you can have a home web server that your regular everyday router is directing port 80 activity to, can you still have normal users on their devices being able to access port 80 e.g. through web browsers.

Comment: You mean having people inside your router be able to access it too? Sure. Say your machine is 192.168.1.5 and your router redirects to it, then machines inside your network (192.168.1.xxx) should be able to go to that address without going through your router; they could also access the external address and go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes almost every router today supports the feature you described here. But buy default port 80 is consumed by router itself  to manage router application. So you can use a feature called port forwarding in your router to get access to your specified applications on specific ports.

Comment: hey thanks for your quick reply. So you would forward the port 80 in portforward of my router, correct?

Comment: Yes if your router does support that. As router too has a webserver installed so it will too require port 80. In that case if router has facility provide custom port to itself.